# How to add object to list (or other collection) that is inside another object?

Tags: wcf, linq

I have this:

```
    public class Room
{
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public List<User> UsersInRoom { get; set; }

    //public IDuplexClient RoomCallbackChannel { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is an List that contains users in room.

But to actually make it work I need to add users, so I did this:

```
            User usr;
        Room roomi;
        if (userNameTest == null)
        {
            lock (_clients)
            {
                usr = new User { UserID = sessionID, CallbackChannel = client, UserName = userName };
                roomi = new Room();
                roomi.RoomID = sessionID;
                roomi.RoomName = room;
                roomi.UsersInRoom.Add(usr);
                //roomi.UsersInRoom.Add(usr);
                _rooms.Add(roomi);
                //_clients.Add(usr);
            }
        }
```

and at line:

```
roomi.UsersInRoom.Add(usr);
```

I get NullReferenceException.
What's going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created a list - so `roomi.UsersInRoom` is null.

You could fix this by changing the line to:

```
roomi.UsersInRoom = new List<User>();
roomi.UsersInRoom.Add(usr);
```

Note that if you're using C# 3 or higher, you can use object and collection initializers to make all of this code simpler. Additionally, you could potentially make `UsersInRoom` a read-only property, setting the value to a new list within a `Room` constructor (or a variable initializer).

Unfortunately I don't have time to show all of this right now, but something like this for the object/collection initializers:

```
_rooms.Add(new Room {
    RoomId = sessionId,
    RoomName = room,
    UsersInRoom = new List<User> { 
        new User { 
            UserID = sessionID,
            CallbackChannel = client,
            UserName = userName
        }
    }
});
```

If you change it so that `UsersInRoom` is initialized by Room itself, this changes to:

```
_rooms.Add(new Room {
    RoomId = sessionId,
    RoomName = room,
    UsersInRoom = { 
        new User { 
            UserID = sessionID,
            CallbackChannel = client,
            UserName = userName
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This was to obvious. Thanks.
I have used Object Initializer for usr. But how can I do same thing for Room ?

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>`, is a reference type. The default value for a reference type is `null`.

You need to initialise the List before you start adding items to it.

```
roomi.UsersInRoom=new List<User>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the `List` is initialized? List is an object so you have to 'create' it, like so:

```
List<User> nameOfList = new List<User>();
```